# Extract array from object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a component who receive props:

The data recived printed on console.log

[image]

How to extract the array from this object?

Before I send the array to my component look like this:

[image]

Comment: `variable.data` is the array, where `variable` is the variable that holds the object.

Comment: Voting to re-open because this about about react components

Comment: variable.data works Thank you very much.

Comment: @alex what?! How is tht different? Also I can see anything React specific here.

Comment: @JonasWilms I admit it's a hunch based on _"I have a component who receive props:"_. Also, because fetching a property from an object is kind of a different thing than understanding how props being passed to a react component map to the props inside that component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing

`console.log(props);`

you can get the array with:

`const arr = props.data;`

or

`const { data } = props;`

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used the function map() to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a React component that is receive data like this:

```
<MyComponent data={myArray} />
```

If so, then inside that component, it will receive it on the prop named `data`.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  console.log(props.data)
  return <p>{data}</p>
}
```

Or written with the more common destructuring assignment:

```
function MyComponent({data}) {
  console.log(data)
  return <p>{data}</p>
}
```

Comment: So how's `console.log(props.data)` not covered by the duplicate?

Comment: @JonasWilms According to the questioner, a component receives props `{ data: myArray }`, but the data started as just `myArray`. So in addition to explaining how to get that data, I believed it worth explaining where the `data` property on this object came from, since that seemed unclear to the questioner, especially considering their apparent level of expertise. So I thought a generic answer about how to get a property from a variable might be inadequate. I sometimes see questions closed as duplicates that fail to adequately connect the questioners code to the solution cleanly.